# Firebird sends all events in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, events, firebird, firebird-.net-provider

Is it normal firebird server sends all registered event counts on raising any of registered event?

By example on firebirds site I do this:

```
class FirebirdListenerTest
{
    public FirebirdListenerTest()
    {
        try
        {
            FbConnectionStringBuilder cs = new FbConnectionStringBuilder();
            cs.DataSource = "localhost";
            cs.Database = "C:\\FIREBIRD\\TEST.GDB";
            cs.UserID = "SYSDBA";
            cs.Password = "masterkey";
            cs.Charset = "NONE";

            FbConnection connection = new FbConnection(cs.ToString());
            connection.Open();

            FbRemoteEvent revent = new FbRemoteEvent(connection);
            revent.AddEvents(new string[] { "text_changed", "text_inserted", "justtest_event" });

            // Add callback to the Firebird events
            revent.RemoteEventCounts += new FbRemoteEventEventHandler(EventCounts);

            // Queue events
            revent.QueueEvents();

            Console.ReadLine();
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    static void EventCounts(object sender, FbRemoteEventEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Event {0} has {1} counts.", args.Name, args.Counts);
    }
}
```

In such code, if any of events is raised, I always get counts for all events. Is it how it should works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is. You can filter it base on Counts property, it can be 0-n.

Comment: I did it just like you describe. I wanted to be sure. Thank You.